# TikZ how to make supply and demand arrows for nodes?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the nodes and arcs modeled in TikZ, but I'm scratching my head about how to draw the 'supply' and 'demand' double arrows (e.g. demand of 2 on node 1, supply of 2 on node 3). Can anybody help? Thanks

[image: what I want]

current code, which produces the nodes and arcs (ignoring dashed lines), the demand nodes, but not the double-tailed supply and demand arrows:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{pgf, tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, automata, positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[roundnode/.style={circle,draw=black!50,thick},
supplynode/.style={circle},
 > = stealth, % arrow head style
            shorten > = 1pt, % don't touch arrow head to node
            auto,
            node distance = 3cm, % distance between nodes
            semithick % line style
]
        \node at (0,0)      [roundnode] (n1) {1};
        \node at (2.5,2.5)  [roundnode] (n2) {2};
        \node at (0.0,5.0)  [roundnode] (n3) {3};
        \node at (5.0,0.0)  [roundnode] (n4) {4};
        \node at (5.0,4.0)  [roundnode] (n5) {5};
        \node at (10.0,5.0) [roundnode] (n6) {6};
        \node at (10.0,0.0) [roundnode] (n7) {7};
        \node at (7.5,2.5)  [roundnode] (n8) {8};

        \node at (-1.0, -1.0) [supplynode] (s1) {2};
        \node at (2.5, 3.5)   [supplynode] (s2) {1};
        \node at (-1.0, 6.0)  [supplynode] (s3) {2};
        \node at (5.0,-1.0)   [supplynode] (s4) {6};
        \node at (6.0,4.0)    [supplynode] (s5) {2};
        \node at (11.0,0.0)   [supplynode] (s7) {5};

        \path[->] (n1) edge node {0} (n3);
        \path[->] (n2) edge node {3} (n1);
        \path[->] (n2) edge node {2} (n5);
        \path[->] (n3) edge node {0} (n2);
        \path[->] (n3) edge node {1} (n6);
        \path[->] (n4) edge node {1} (n1);
        \path[->] (n5) edge node {2} (n4);
        \path[->] (n6) edge node {1} (n8);
        \path[->] (n7) edge node {1} (n6);
        \path[->] (n7) edge node {4} (n4);
        \path[->] (n8) edge node {3} (n5);
        \path[->] (n8) edge node {0} (n7);



\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

what the above code produces:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stackexchange! According to our guidelines, it would be appreciated to see some MWE to help you based on your current code. Thanks a lot!

Comment: with `Implies[]` from `arrows.meta` library?

Comment: Thanks @Dave, what is MWE?

Comment: @user1757226 see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/63847.

Comment: well, this is only code snippet :-). *mwe*(minimal working example) is complete document beginning with `\documentclass` with needed packages and your definitions in preamble following with document body with your code snippet and with `\end{document}` on the end.

Comment: @Zarko - updated with complete MWE.

Answer (score 4):

OK, I'm sure there's a better way to organize things inside the Tikz, but I have found a sufficient answer to my question myself. Posting here for posterity.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{pgf, tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, automata, positioning, arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[roundnode/.style={circle,draw=black!50,thick},
supplynode/.style={circle} ,
 > = stealth, % arrow head style
            shorten > = 1pt, % don't touch arrow head to node
            auto,
            node distance = 3cm, % distance between nodes
            semithick % line style
]
        \node at (0,0)      [roundnode] (n1) {1};
        \node at (2.5,2.5)  [roundnode] (n2) {2};
        \node at (0.0,5.0)  [roundnode] (n3) {3};
        \node at (5.0,0.0)  [roundnode] (n4) {4};
        \node at (5.0,4.0)  [roundnode] (n5) {5};
        \node at (10.0,5.0) [roundnode] (n6) {6};
        \node at (10.0,0.0) [roundnode] (n7) {7};
        \node at (7.5,2.5)  [roundnode] (n8) {8};

        \node at (-1.0, -1.0) [supplynode] (s1) {2};
        \node at (2.5, 4.0)   [supplynode] (s2) {1};
        \node at (-1.0, 6.0)  [supplynode] (d3) {2};
        \node at (5.0,-1.5)   [supplynode] (s4) {6};
        \node at (6.5,4.0)    [supplynode] (d5) {2};
        \node at (11.5,0.0)   [supplynode] (d7) {5};

        \path[->] (n1) edge node {0} (n3);
        \path[->] (n2) edge node {3} (n1);
        \path[->] (n2) edge node {2} (n5);
        \path[->] (n3) edge node {0} (n2);
        \path[->] (n3) edge node {1} (n6);
        \path[->] (n4) edge node {1} (n1);
        \path[->] (n5) edge node {2} (n4);
        \path[->] (n6) edge node {1} (n8);
        \path[->] (n7) edge node {1} (n6);
        \path[->] (n7) edge node {4} (n4);
        \path[->] (n8) edge node {3} (n5);
        \path[->] (n8) edge node {0} (n7);

        \draw[-Implies,line width=1pt,double distance=2pt] (n1) -- (s1);
        \draw[-Implies,line width=1pt,double distance=2pt] (n2) -- (s2);
        \draw[-Implies,line width=1pt,double distance=2pt] (d3) -- (n3);
        \draw[-Implies,line width=1pt,double distance=2pt] (n4) -- (s4);
        \draw[-Implies,line width=1pt,double distance=2pt] (d5) -- (n5);
        \draw[-Implies,line width=1pt,double distance=2pt] (d7) -- (n7);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

produces this, which is sufficient for my needs. Thanks @Zarko for the tip.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

let me convert my comments to the answer ... with some off-topic sugestion :-) :

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, 
                quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto=left,
every edge/.style = {draw, semithick, -Stealth, shorten > = 1pt},
                        ]
    \begin{scope}[every node/.style={circle, draw=black!50, thick}]
\node at ( 0.0,0)   (n1) {1};
\node at ( 2.5,2.5) (n2) {2};
\node at ( 0.0,5.0) (n3) {3};
\node at ( 5.0,0.0) (n4) {4};
\node at ( 5.0,4.0) (n5) {5};
\node at (10.0,5.0) (n6) {6};
\node at (10.0,0.0) (n7) {7};
\node at ( 7.5,2.5) (n8) {8};
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[every node/.style={circle}]
\node at (-1.0,-1.0) (s1) {2};
\node at ( 2.5, 4.0) (s2) {1};
\node at (-1.0, 6.0) (d3) {2};
\node at ( 5.0,-1.5) (s4) {6};
\node at ( 6.5, 4.0) (d5) {2};
\node at (11.5, 0.0) (d7) {5};
    \end{scope}
\path   (n1) edge ["0"] (n3)
        (n2) edge ["3"] (n1)
        (n2) edge ["2"] (n5)
        (n3) edge ["0"] (n2)
        (n3) edge ["1"] (n6)
        (n4) edge ["1"] (n1)
        (n5) edge ["2"] (n4)
        (n6) edge ["1"] (n8)
        (n7) edge ["1"] (n6)
        (n7) edge ["4"] (n4)
        (n8) edge ["3"] (n5)
        (n8) edge ["0"] (n7);
    \begin{scope}[every edge/.style = {draw, -Implies, semithick, double distance=1pt}]
\path   (n1) edge (s1)
        (n2) edge (s2)
        (d3) edge (n3)
        (n4) edge (s4)
        (d5) edge (n5)
        (d7) edge (n7);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

above *mwe* gives:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Zarko. Your solution is a much more elegant use of Tikz. My solution is definitely brute-force copy/paste to get the job done.

Comment: @user1757226, to be precise: your answer with my suggestion :-), and my answer with my suggestion + off-topic improvements ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I would use loops to avoid repetition and pins for the double arrows, which can be attached with `\node also`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[roundnode/.style={circle,draw=black!50,thick},
supplynode/.style={circle},
every pin edge/.append style={line width=1pt,double distance=2pt,draw},
 > = stealth, % arrow head style
 shorten > = 1pt, % don't touch arrow head to node
 semithick % line style
]
  \foreach [count=\X] \Coord in 
  {(0,0),(2.5,2.5),(0.0,5.0),(5.0,0.0),(5.0,4.0),(10.0,5.0),(10.0,0.0),(7.5,2.5)}
  {\node[roundnode] (n\X) at \Coord {\X};}
  \foreach \X/\Y/\Z in {1/below left/2,2/above/1,4/below/6}
  {\node also  [pin={[pin distance=8mm,pin edge={-Implies}]\Y:\Z}]  (n\X);}
  \foreach \X/\Y/\Z in {3/above left/2,5/right/2,7/right/5}
  {\node also  [pin={[pin distance=8mm,pin edge={Implies-}]\Y:\Z}]  (n\X);}
  \foreach \X/\Y/\Z in {1/0/3,2/3/1,2/2/5,3/0/2,3/1/6,4/1/1,5/2/4,6/1/8,7/1/6,7/4/4,8/3/5,8/0/7}
  {\draw[->] (n\X) -- (n\Z) node[midway,auto]{\Y};} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

One could reduce it to two loops at the expense of introducing some ifs. With `graphdrawing` one could avoid the need of introducing explicit coordinates and/or distances altogether but this would require `lualatex`.